# PostgreSQLCopyHelper BulkImportData

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment, bulkinsert

Postgres table def

`CREATE TABLE MyTable ( myKey BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY, amount         INT, description    TEXT );`

Here's my copy helper inserting from List of values.

```
var copyHelper = new PostgreSQLCopyHelper<BulkImportData>("", "MyTable")            
                                    .MapInteger("amount", x => x.amount)
                                    .MapText("description", x => x.desc);
```

The Saveall throws error - myKey is not defined.

But mykey is SERIAL auto increment, I cannot set it explicitly.

How to specify a SERIAL auto increment in a PostgreSQLCopyHelper?

Thank you

Comment: Please add a tag for the language and/or framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

My bad.    The primary key was not declared auto increment.

New declaration:
`myKey BIGINT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 )`

Now it works.